# Bokeh plot using a function of values in ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, glyph

I'd like to plot a glyph using a function of the values in a ColumnDataSource instead of the raw values.

As a minimum example, suppose I want to plot a point that the user can drag, which moves another point around. The position of the second point is some arbitrary function of the position of the first point.

I can draw the second point right on top of the first point like so:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import PointDrawTool, ColumnDataSource, Circle

p = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=[],
           title='Point Draw Tool')

source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': [1], 'y': [1], 'color': ['red']
})

# plot a point at x,y
renderer = p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='color', size=10)

# create a circle at the same position as the point
glyph = Circle(x='x',y='y', size=30)
p.add_glyph(source, glyph)

# allow the user to move the point at x,y
draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer], empty_value='black')
p.add_tools(draw_tool)
p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

show(p)
```

This plot draws the second point with exactly the same `(x,y)` coordinates as the first point.

Now, suppose I'd like to draw the second point at some arbitrary function of the first point `(f(x,y), g(x,y))` for a pair of arbitrary functions `f()` and `g()`. To make it simple, let's say the coordinates of the new point are `(2x, 2y)` .

Can someone tell me how to do this?

I'd like to do something like

```
glyph = Circle(x=2*'x',y=2*'y', size=30)
p.add_glyph(source, glyph)
```

Clearly this is not how to do it, but hopefully this makes it clear what I'm trying to do. In general, I'd like to do something like:

```
glyph = Circle(x=f('x','y'), y=g('x','y'), size=30)
p.add_glyph(source, glyph)
```

I have tried something silly like the following:

```
def get_circle(x,y):
   new_x = 2*x
   new_y = 2*y
   return Circle(x=new_x, y=new_y, size=30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `ColumnDataSource` and use a `CustomJS` to apply changes to your data.

In the example below I create a default `source`, add two renderers to a figure, define a JavaScript callback and excecute the callback every time the `source` changes.
Because I link the only one renderer to the `PointDrawTool`, the second renderer is updated, after I moved the frist renderer.

#### Minimal Example

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, PointDrawTool
output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x1=[1,3],
    y1=[2,3],
    x2=[2,6],
    y2=[6,9]
))


p = figure(width=300, height=300)
r1 = p.circle(x='x1', y='y1', color='blue', source=source, size=5)
r2 = p.triangle(x='x2', y='y2', color='green', source=source, size=5)

draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[r1], empty_value='black')
p.add_tools(draw_tool)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source),
    code="""
    function f(x) {
      return x*2;
    };
    function g(y) {
      return y*3;
    };

    let data = source.data
    data['x2'] = data['x1'].map(f)
    data['y2'] = data['y1'].map(g)

    source.change.emit()
    """
)

source.js_on_change('data', callback)
show(p)
```

#### Result

[image: updating a renderer by other changed renderer]

#### Comment

The example can have even more `cirlce`s and `triangle`s but at the moment only one can be moved and updated at a time and the order matters.

Really hope this helps you.

Comment: That gets me nearly all the way there. I'd actually like to not modify the original data source for the circle so I edited your response a bit (see my updated answer), but using the callback solved it. Thank you!